# C syntax /AVR headers

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, microcontroller, avr

I am trying to understand [this](https://sites.google.com/site/hackskunk/home/attiny85-hacks/motion-detector) code

But I am having trouble understanding this part of the code.

```
#define cbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) &= -_BV(bit))
#define sbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) |= _BV(bit))
```

`sbi` and `cbi` are later being used in the code as

```
void system_sleep()
{
  sbi(MCUCR,PUD);                                  //Disables All Internal Pullup Resistors
  sbi(GIMSK,PCIE);                                   //Enable Pin Change Interrupts Interrups
  sbi(PCMSK,PCINT0);                              //Changes Interrupt to PIN1 (PCINT1) 
  cbi(ADCSRA,ADEN);                              //switch Analog to Digital Converter OFF
  cbi(MCUCR,SM0);                                  //Power Down Mode
  sbi(MCUCR,SM1);                                  //Power Down Mode
  sbi(MCUCR,SE);   //sleep Mode Power down enable (Sleep_enable(); should set this-- not tested yet)
  sleep_enable();                      //Sets the Sleep Enable bit in the MCUCR Register (SE BIT)
  sleep_mode();                                       //sleep begins here
  sleep_disable();                                     //Coming out of sleep
  sbi(ADCSRA,ADEN);                             //switch Analog to Digital Converter ON
  cbi(MCUCR,PUD); //Enables Pullup Resistors Again 
 }
```

The code is for `ATtiny85` and I read the data sheet and I came to know that all these like `MCCUR` and `ADCSRA` etc are all registers. Also it states that there are two kinds of instructions `SBI` and `CBI`.

I also read some tutorials about micro controller programming using C and understand that each register has `8` bits. Each of these bits can be set using programming for different functionality. Also `PUD`, `PCIE` are different bits of these registers and these are being set in the `system_sleep` function. So I understand what `system_sleep` function is doing , it is setting the bits in the register.

The only part I am not able to understand is

```
#define cbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) &= -_BV(bit))
#define sbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) |= _BV(bit))
```

There is nothing in the data sheet like `_SFR_BYTE` or `_BV`. I looked into AVR/libc headers, there I found `_BV` but not sure what is it doing.

Answer (score 3):

The names of the macros should give you some hint. `cbi` stands for `Clear Bit` and `sbi` stands for `Set Bit`. `cbi(sfr, bit)` clears bit-number indicated by `bit` in the register `sfr`. Similar explanation for `sbi`.

If you have the whole project, you can search for the definition of `_SFR_BYTE` and `_BV`. But in essense they roughly translate into

```
#define  cbi(sfr, bit)   ((sfr) &= ~(1 << (bit)))

#define  sbi(sfr, bit)   ((sfr) |= (1 << (bit)))
```

Read more about [bit-masking](http://kineticsandelectronics.com/node/104).

Comment: But you win, since you use `~`; the OP's code uses `-` for the clearing case which seems super-scary. When talking about bits, don't suddenly involve arithmetic.

Comment: @unwind Well since we don't know what _BV() is, the subtraction could be the correct thing to do.

Comment: What does `sfr` stand for?

Comment: @seth10 "Special Function Registers".

Answer (score 1):

```
#define _BV(bit)       (1 << (bit))
#define _SFR_BYTE(sfr) _MMIO_BYTE(_SFR_ADDR(sfr))
```

The first one `_BV`, as an example, instead of writing `1<<0`  in your code you can write just `_BV(0)`.
The second one `_SFR_BYTE` uses the `_MMIO_BYTE` macro to get the data from the register sfr which could be MCUCR or ADCSRA or any 8bit IO register.

For more information refer to [avr/sfr_defs.h](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/sfr__defs_8h_source.html)

Answer (score 0):

The AVR ATMega registers from 0x00 to 0x1F may be read / written using the in and out instructions, moreover specific instructions that works on these registers there're . These registers may be also read using memory instructions. In this case those register addresses must take the values from 0x20 to 0x3F.

The macros __SFR_xxxx take in account this behavior.

These are quotes of the notes of the paragraph "Register Summary" of the ATMega 2560:

> -2. I/O registers within the address range $00 - $1F are directly bit-accessible using the SBI and CBI instructions. In these reg-
>   isters, the value of single bits can be checked by using the SBIS and
>   SBIC instructions.
>
> -4. When using the I/O specific commands IN and OUT, the I/O addresses $00 - $3F must be used. When addressing I/O regis- ters as data space
>   using LD and ST instructions, $20 must be added to these addresses.
>   The ATmega640/1280/1281/2560/2561 is a complex microcontroller with
>   more peripheral units than can be supported within the 64 location
>   reserved in Opcode for the IN and OUT instructions. For the Extended
>   I/O space from $60 - $1FF in SRAM, only the ST/STS/STD and LD/LDS/LDD
>   instructions can be used.